# Ionic2 - How to push a new page in root component every time a user goes to root component?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a login page as root component with a function that checks if user is already authenticated therefore pushes a new view. The problem is that all the other views start to overlap like in the image below.
[Here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF2eX.png)

Everything works fine when I use this but I need it to run every time a user goes to the login page:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    if(this.auth.authenticated()){
        this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
    } 
}
```

This checks if the user is authenticated every time but causes the overlapping. Can someone explain why this happens?

```
onPageWillEnter() {
        if(this.auth.authenticated()){
            this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can suggest you something : you shouldn't push a view in your case, but directly changing the rootPage, this way your app will directly load the right view.

To do that it's pretty easy, go to your `app.js`.

```
rootPage: any = null;

constructor(private platform: Platform) {
  platform.ready().then(() => {  
    if(this.auth.authenticated())
      this.rootPage = HomePage;
    else
      this.rootPage = Login;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Can't believe I couldn't think of this earlier :)

Comment: Haha! It happens! ;-)